# Radio Button Values not being passed/ posted to php script

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am having some trouble getting radio button values to post to my php script.

I have followed a few example solutions via StackOverflow but they still don't seem to be working. I may be missing something which I hope someone can figure out.

**welcome.html**

```
<form method="POST "action="./php/welcome-mood.php">

     <table>
        <tr><td><img class="moodIcon" alt="good" src="img/moods/good.png" /></td>
            <td align="left"><input required="true" type="radio" name="radioMood" value="Good"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><img class="moodIcon" alt="ok" src="img/moods/ok.png" /></td><td align="left"><input required="true" type="radio" name="radioMood" value="Ok"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><img class="moodIcon" alt="bad" src="img/moods/bad.png" /></td><td align="left"><input required="true" type="radio" name="radioMood" value="Bad"/></td></tr>
        <br />
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" /></td></tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

**welcome-mood.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $todayMood = $_POST['radioMood'];

    echo $todayMood;
}
```

Comment: And what is the output?

Comment: Confirm the path of your action attribute on the submit form. Meaning does it point to the right path('./php/welcome-mood.php')?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the `$_POST` variable, with `var_dump($_POST);`? It might reveal something.

Comment: i get no output with the if condition, if i simply try echo out the variable, it is undefined.

Comment: using var_dump(_$POST) i get: array(0) { }

and can confirm the action attribute is pointing to the correct location yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the `<form`tag - you have a typo in `method="POST "` vs `method="POST"`, so the form is submitted by default GET method.

```
   <form method="POST" action="./php/welcome-mood.php">
   ...
   ...
```

Comment: aww jeez i knew there would be something silly in there! many thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You have put "action=" in inverted comma.

Replace   method="POST "action="   by    method="POST" action="

Hope this helps.Take care of the spaces between POST and ".